# Training a neural network with two completely different datasets.

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, training-data

I am working with Neural network for object classification right now. I am working on creating datasets for training and validation. I want to know if it is possible to create two datasets for training comprising of two completely different objects and labels. (EG  dataset 1 has cars and dataset 2 has cats) Does it still work or should I create datasets where each file has mixed up both the different object types and labels in all the training files? Does such mixture/separation matter if I am training the network in one cycle with different datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using to train, many APIs (such as TensorFlow object detection) read the TF Record files (datasets) in order as they are scrambled to make the files beforehand. Scrambling is quite important with training as you will get the model starting training with one class, and then train for a bit with another individual class. It should get to the same standard eventually, but it is a lot better for the model to train with an equal distribution of classes of the training steps.